# How do i load in data that has been encrypted to use?

Tags: python, encryption

im not very good with titles so let me break it down here

im using python to create a very basic encrypted login/create account feature for a game im developing, but i keep running into a `buffer error` and i cant get python to decrypt data that was stored in a dict
ive tried several methods to verify a password

```
json
pickle
file = open
encrypting the password and comparing it with to password on the file
decrying the files password and comparing it with and input
comparing the encrypted data to the encrypted data
```

ive been struggling with this for a week and i have asked this multiple times over on replit.com but no one seems to be able to help me

here is my code

```
def login():
  while True:
    print('enter your username')

    username = input()
    print('enter password')
    password = input().encode()

    try:
      with open(username, 'rb') as userdata:
        user = pl(userdata)

        f = c(user['key'])

        password = f.encrypt(password)
        if password == user['password']:
          print(user)
        
        else:
          print(user['password'],'\n')
          print(password)
    except FileNotFoundError:
      print('invalid username or password')
```

Comment: Please state your problem clearly.
you haven't shown any error or defined the specific problem.
you may refer to asking guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello, is your question how to decrypt the data? Is so, can you show how you encrypt it?